# Converting CSV into Array in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, typeconverter

I have a csv file like below. A small csv file and I have uploaded it [here](https://file.io/Wo0bFb9HZoYJ)

[image]

I am trying to convert csv values into array.

**My expectation output like**

[image]

**My solution**

```
results = []
with open("Solutions10.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) # change contents to floats
    for row in reader: # each row is a list
        results.append(row)
```

but I am getting a

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' [1'

Comment: In your own words, what is a CSV file, and what is that format good for? In your own words, how do you expect a row of data to be represented in a CSV file normally? In particular: when you open CSV files created by other people, do you see `[]` surrounding each row? The problem here is not with the code, but the data.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  Post the actual text of the input file as text so it can be used to test solutions.  Don't expect us to type up the data ourselves from an image.  Links are also frowned upon as they can rot and make the question invalid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
with open("Solutions10.csv") as csvfile:
    result = [eval(k) for k in csvfile.readlines()]
```

Edit: Karl is cranky and wants you todo this:

```
with open("Solutions10.csv") as csvfile:
    result = []
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        line = line.replace("[","").replace("]","")
        result.append([int(k) for k in line.split(",")]
```

But you're the programmer so you can do what you want. If you trust your input file eval is fine.

Comment: Please do not suggest something as dangerous as `eval` for something this straightforward; and please do not lead people *away from* using the CSV module for parsing what is intended to be a CSV file. The underlying problem is that the file is not using the CSV format in a sensible way.

Comment: about new edit... if the string ends in "]," - you will get ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```. if you don't have this ending coma - ignore. Otherwise  maybe add  ```.replace("],", "").replace("]", "")``` to try to cover as much problematic things as possible.

Comment: No; I want OP to start with data in a format that actually makes sense and is honestly labelled. I am not "cranky"; I am concerned about the cyber security of future visitors of the site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your CSV. It's just not csv (coma separated values). To do this you need some cleaning:

```py
import re

# if you expect only integers
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+')
# if you expect floats (uncomment below)
# pattern = re.compile(r'\d+\.*\d*')
result = []
with open(filepath) as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        result.append([
            int(val.group(0))
            # float(val.group(0))
            for val in re.finditer(pattern, row)
        ])
        
print(result)
```

You can also solve this with substrings if it's easier for you and you know the format exactly.

Note: Also I see there is "eval" suggestion. Please, be careful with it as you can get into a lot of trouble if you scan unknown/not trusted files...

Comment: I don't know what's worse goto or eval...

Comment: @kpie I don't really do goto... (or I didn't understand what you mean). I grab all the numerical values here and put it in the list...

Comment: Yeah no your code is fine and dandy I was just making a joke.